# Telegram bot using polling not giving any response

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-3.7, python-telegram-bot

I created a Telegram bot in Python (3.7) to retrieve articles from a website. I used the start_polling() method from the Python telegram bot library to get commands from the user, but when I run the file in my command line (Windows OS), there is no response at all. The file keeps running and doesn't terminate, and any messages sent to the bot aren't responded to either. The code snippet is given below.

```
YOUR_TOKEN = secret!
WELCOME = 'Welcome!'


def brain_pickings():
  final_reply = pickings()
  bot.sendMessage(text=final_reply,parse_mode='html')


updater = Updater(token=YOUR_TOKEN)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', my_start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('brainpickings', brain_pickings))
updater.start_polling()
print('it is happening!')
updater.idle()
print('it is idle!')
```

The bot does not respond to /start or /brainpickings. The output on the command line (where I had entered the command to run the file):

```
C:\Users\ANJALI\.vscode\telegbot>python main.py
it is happening!
```

PS - pickings() is a separate function I defined to retrieve the articles. It runs perfectly fine on its own. Please let me know if it needs to be added here.

Comment: Have you tried to [enable logging](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/f7abb213234549ef2b1940cc17479eb0fdb19ef6/examples/echobot2.py#L24)? This could help since I do not see any problem with your current code.

Comment: Hi! I enabled logging like you said. Turns out that I hadn't imported my modules for the article retrieval properly. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Nice! I recommend keeping logging enabled while developing since the framework will swallow all errors and it will look like nothing is done at all

Answer (score 0):

I got the bot to run. I tried logging as was suggested in the comment above, and there was some error with the way I had imported my modules. The code is fine otherwise.